# Set-AzStorageBlobContent : Illegal characters in path

Tags: azure, path, character, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I've been trying to upload content to blob using below az command using azure runbook , but it's throwing error as illegal characters in path. kindly assist

Set-AzStorageBlobContent : Illegal characters in path

Comment: What is the command you're running?

Comment: Hi Shruthi kallur, Looks like it is related to [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/12220/) / [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/8531/) issue.